# Returning a child element by its class type in android

Tags: java, android

I have  question.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#239"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

And a function to return the first child view of the given parentid:

```
public View findViewByType(int parentId, Class<?> type){
    LinearLayout rootLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(parentId);
    int count = rootLinearLayout.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View v = rootLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), v.getClass().getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (v.getClass() ==  type) return v;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm Inflating a view using the `question.xml` layout like and then trying to get the RadioGroup from it:

```
        LinearLayout q = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.question, null);
        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewByType(q.getId(), RadioGroup.class);
```

The `rg` is `null`

When I test it like:

```
q.getChildAt(0).getClass().GetName();  //return TextView = Correct
q.getChildAt(1).getClass().GetName(); //returns RadioGroup = Correct
```

but in the function `findViewByType` loop, value of v for:

i=1 is `TextView` which is Correct

i=2 is `LinearLayout` which is **INCORRECT**

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I tried to set Id for the inflated `LinearLayout` before calling the function but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uhmm.. `LinearLayout` is the enclosing class of `RadioGroup` i will say go for this rather

```
v.getClass().isAssignableFrom(type) && (type.isInstance(v))//did it work?
```

maybe this rather?

```
(v.getClass() ==  type) || (v.getClass().isAssignableFrom(type) && 
                          v.getClass().equals(type.getEnclosingClass()))
```